# Create another list from a list in Sencha touch

Tags: json, jsonp, sencha-touch-2

I am stuck at what seems to be a simple thing to do,

I am new to the whole Sencha touch environment and still need to get my head around a lot of things.

here is the issue Im facing,

I have built the gettingStarted app from Sencha homepage, this app is simple where it loads a list from JSON data & on clicking the item in the list, it shows the HTML content of the chosen item

What Im trying to do is create another list so that

1- List one loads on startup
2- On clicking an item in List 1, it loads another list 2
3- on cicking the list 2, it loads the HTML content.

I have written webservice to return data as JSON based on which I would like to build the second list.

Im calling a function "showPost" on itemTap and it looks like this:

```
 showPost: function(list, index, element, record){
    Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'http://localhost/mobig/ws/search.php?cat='+record.get('category'),            
        success: function(response){
            var text = response.responseText;
            var responses = Ext.JSON.decode(response.responseText);

            alert(responses.posts[0].title);
        }
    });
```

I also have, this:

```
    this.getBlog().setData({
        xtype:'panel',
        title:record.get('category'),
        html:'<img src='+record.get('imageURL')+'/>',
        scrollable:true,
        styleHTMLContent:true
    });
}
```

which loads the HTML content from List 1.

Thanks for your help in advance, and sorry about the bad english,

If you can point me to some examples, It will be a good place to learn.

Thanks!
Mo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient way to save your time is to use **Ext.NestedList**, but I don't recommend it because currently nested list performance in Sencha Touch 2 is still so terrible (scrolling, event catching, etc.), if you care more about performance, you should use **2 seperated Ext.List**, for eg. list_one with store_one and list_two with store_two, when list_one fires `itemtap` event, catch `record` parameter and process it (maybe through reading a `TreeStore`, or write your own API such as http://yourdomain/api=get_list_two&record_from_list_one=record)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Thiem, thanks for the input, let me give this a shot, I was going through sencha videos and learnt that I should create a separate view for each of the lists and create the view on the function load. I have already written my api's before to return JSON data, but again, Im having a hard time trying to createJSON data, are you aware of any examples which show dynamically building JSON data?

Comment: this also depends on what your back-end server returns, I mean web APIs. Do you mean JSON data format from web API which is convenient to build each list's data records or simply the way to process them? I'm not sure I understood your point so please explain more concretely

Comment: Hi Thiem, Haven't still found a solution for this, but we are still working with Nested List to see if it can do what we want, ideally, this is what I aim to get done: 1) my-app(loads), 2) I have a screen that displays some options 3) on click of one of the option/category on screen 1, it takes me to screen 2 with a list of more options 4) once I select another option from there, it shows a page with the HTML...Can I do it with 2 webservice calls to retrieve different sets of json data? if so, can you please point me to an example, or, should I go with the nested List. Thanks,

Comment: if you want to use `Ext.NestedList`, simply follow the example in ST2 docs and the result JSON file could be something like this: http://apis.coa.vn/?api=nested-group. Or if you want to use 2 separated `Ext.List` (which gives a better performance), you can add an additional field to your Model definition, let's say `parent`. First list options has `parent` = 0, and second list options has `parent` pointed to `id` of first option. Then use `filter` function of `Ext.data.Store`. It's how I've done to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to set up a nested list.  [Here's the nested list tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/nested_list), which should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks Briguy, nested list is ideally how I want to get done, let me see if this works, thanks for your input :)